# Validate the current row actual data with edited data before saving in inlinenav jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to compare and validate the current row actual data(from server) with the edited/updated data(entered by the user in run time) when i move on to other row without saving the current row.

If the validation returns 'true' i should show the confirm message "Do you want save the changes?" else nothing.

Note: Need to compare each cell of my current row.

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks.